# PHPExcel Timeout occur

Tags: php, mysql, memory, timeout, phpexcel

Please help me for the the problem exporting large data to excel format xlsx.
i m exporting almost 45000 records at a time to single file and it timeout without saving file.
the mysql select query is taking 21 seconds for executing that large data. Below is my code to export data in to Excel file using PHP Excel library.

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Surveys";
 $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{   
$j=$rowscounter+2;
$sheet->setCellValue("A$j",$row2['brandname']);
$sheet->setCellValue("B$j",$row2['productname']);
$sheet->setCellValue("C$j",$row2['sname']);
$sheet->setCellValue("D$j",$row2['smobile']);
$sheet->setCellValue("E$j",$row2['semail']);
$sheet->setCellValue("F$j",$row2['country']);
$sheet->setCellValue("G$j",$row2['city']);
$sheet->setCellValue("H$j",$row2['sdob']);
$sheet->setCellValue("I$j",$row2['age']);
$sheet->setCellValue("J$j",$row2['comment']);
$sheet->setCellValue("K$j",$row2['outletcode']);
$sheet->setCellValue("L$j",$row2['username']);
$sheet->setCellValue("M$j",$row2['datetime']);
$sheet->setCellValue("N$j",$row2['duration']);  
$rowscounter++;
}

 // Rename worksheet
 $sheet->setTitle('Survey-Report');    
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
 $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
 unlink("Survey-Report.xlsx");
 $objWriter->save('Survey-Report.xlsx');
 echo "ok";
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention that I already tried set_timout etc and wrote below code in my php file.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2500M');
```

Comment: There is a variable within the php.ini that [sets a timeout][1] for php script execution. If you bump that up that may solve your problems.




  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 1):

You could add this at the top of your script:

```
set_time_limit (0);
```

That will disable the default 30 seconds php timeout.

Or you could add a custom number of seconds, see [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I updated my description. I already added that and no luck with that.

Comment: Ok, in that case, if you are getting a `timeout` then, it could be an Apache timeout (or equivalent for other webserver) as read here http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I keep on getting a 504 Gateway Timeout when exporting records using PHPExcel. I also tried `set_time_limit(0)` with no success. What I ended up doing is changing the apache timeout.

You can find this `timout` in your httpd.conf file.

Hope it helps!